# How to sum up weighed normalizations of columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Say, I have a sheet with the following (simplified) structure with absolute values:

[image]

What I want to achieve is to get a table with the normalized values (i.e. the maximum is equivalent to 1. In my example in `value_1`, `4` is maximum and hence `1` and `2` would equal `0.5`). Finally, I want to weigh `value_1` and `value_2` and get a normalized total (maximum number = 1)

Of course, my real sheet has many rows and a couple more columns, so creating new columns in the same sheet is not what I want.

Here is the simplified solution (with an example weigh (`0,6-0,4`):

[image]

Now the question is:

How can I get that solution with a large sheet with hundreds of rows and dozens of columns?

I tried to create a Pivot table and I could get sorts of normalized results for each column:

- Make the column `values` and use `Show values as... > % of column results` (see next screenshot, sorry, German version of Excel)
- I could not get the weighed total with this version though

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 - using formula in additional sheet

- Duplicate your sheet and do the calculations in the second  one. (duplication is good as you have the same headers and range of data as in the original one).
- If you put weights in first row and headers are in the second one then your formula in A3 will look like: `=old_sheet!A3/max(old_sheet!A3:A<last row>)/A1`
- now you only need to summarize rows to get the normalized weighted value

Option 2 - changing original data

- insert 3 new rows at the top of the data
- enter in the new rows: max value of the column, weight, max * weight
- select your 3rd row and press CRTL+C, select all your values and select paste special - divide.
- summarize the rows